# Is powering a sound system from a computer's power supply a bad idea?

Tags: power-supply, computers

While [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/751394/43613) over on Super User looks like it would work, would it be bad for the computer power supply to be the power source for a sound system? Would it cause power fluctuations that would interfere with the other computer components?

The question specifies the following power requirements for the sound bar:

```
    Power requirements: DC 12V +/-5%, 1.0 A
    Total power output: 10 Watts continuous average power
```

The power supply PSU provides 12V DC to disk drives, etc., and that line can be tapped for power to the sound bar.

Answer (score 5):

[A modern ATX12V supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atx#ATX12V_2.x) will easily meet your power spec.¹

Still, there are a number of problems with PC power supplies that make them less than ideal for audio:

- **Switching power**: PC power supplies have always been [switch-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_power_supply#Switched-mode_power_supply) types, rather than [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_power_supply#Linear_regulated_power_supply). Originally, this was simply because of the amount of power that a computer required.²

  [There ain't no such thing as a free lunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanstaafl), so the cost of the higher efficiency of a switcher is that it is electrically noisier than a linear. This isn't a big problem for digital circuitry, especially back in the days of 5 V logic, where a few tens of millivolts of noise was easily ignored by the gate thresholds.

  For audio, though, noise is a problem, since it can indirectly affect the produced waveform.

  I say "indirectly" because almost all amplifiers have some amount of [PSRR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSRR), which rejects rail noise.³ PSRR isn't perfect — there is no such thing as a circuit with infinite PSRR — and it tends to drop as frequency increases, often starting to drop in the audio frequency range.

  When deciding if you have too much rail noise or too little PSRR, you must consider the sensitivity of the human ear, which has [an amazing dynamic range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range).

  *Example:* Your spec says 12 V ±5%, so that allows up to 600 mV of noise and ripple (N+R) on the rails, assuming no DC inaccuracy. Let's say it's really only averaging 100 mV of N+R. Let's also say that at the frequency of the noise on your PC power rail, PSRR is 60 dB. Let's further say that your audio system needs 3 Vac to the speaker to reach 90 dB SPL.⁴ 100 mV is about 30 dB down from 3 V, so adding the 60 dB PSRR, you find that the noise should be right at the threshold of inaudibility: 90 dB SPL operating maximum - 30 dB noise level - 60 dB PSRR = 0 dB SPL noise output, the limit of human hearing.⁵

  *Barely* inaudible, mind. I contrived that example to give that result. Maybe your amplifier has lower PSRR, or higher inherent higher noise, or higher coupled noise from the PC power supply, or a higher output voltage requirement. The point is, PC power rail noise could easily become audible. If this system is used in a quiet room or with closed headphones, so that there is nothing to [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking) the noise, your choice to use a PC power supply might effectively ruin the project.

  Gain and amplifier stage design also play into this. Some amplifiers do their work in multiple stages, each affected by the power supply. If you get -90 dB noise in an early stage which is followed by a gain stage, the noise gets amplified, too. When the amplifier's volume is turned all the way up, it could be 10 dB SPL or more.
- **Shared rail**: Many other parts of the PC will be running from that powerful +12 V rail. Those components will be injecting their own noises into that rail, adding to what the power supply itself produces.

  Some PC power supplies have multiple independent 12 V rails, which would mitigate against this. You may be able to find an unused rail, typically intended for powering high-end graphics cards.
- **Ground noise**: In a sense, this is just an extension of the above, but it has special consequences when it comes to audio systems.

  The ground in an electrical system never has zero impedance, so noises shunted through components to ground don't go to zero. All electrical components produce noise, [Johnson noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_noise) if nothing else.

  Another way ground noise occurs is called "ground bounce," when a component's dynamic current draw creates current-modulated [IR drops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_network_design_(IC)) in the ground plane.

  Still another way the ground gets noisy is because components don't have infinite PSRR, so it couples some *portion* of the power rail's noise to ground.

  Now, what happens to all that ground rail noise when it gets to the audio system? Your speakers are likely to be referenced directly to this PC power ground, for one thing. That means all the PSRR in the amplifier does diddly-squat for reducing this noise. Ground bounce bounces the speaker, which turns it directly into sound energy.

  Is this fatal? Depends on how much ground rail noise there is.
- **Symmetric power**: Some audio circuits require not a single-ended power supply as in your 12 V spec, but instead ±12 V or similar. PC power supplies do still include a -12 V rail, but because almost nothing makes use of it these days, it's always one of the weakest rails in the system, if not *the* weakest.

  Yet, if you don't make use of it, you have to use several hacks to get audio to work on a single-ended system, which themselves harm the sound quality. Capacitive-coupling of the audio signal, for instance, adds [distortions from capacitor imperfections](http://diyaudioprojects.com/mirror/members.aol.com/sbench102/caps.html) to the signal.⁶
- **Shared RFI environment**: PC-based power implies that the audio components will be living inside the RF noise bath inside the computer chassis. That means they're subject to having that RF noise coupled into the audio circuitry, which can result in audio flaws.

---

**Footnotes**:

1. If you're talking instead about scavenging old power supplies from dead computers, you might run into trouble, as the +12V rail was often one of the least powerful, rather than the most powerful.
2. In the early days of PC computing, the CPU unit typically required at least 100 W of continuous power, which would require a pretty big and hot linear power supply. Today, you can get quite capable low-power PCs that run under 10 W, which could reasonably be run from a smallish linear power supply. You still won't find that done commercially, though, since there are now various regulatory and market pressures that require efficient power supplies.
3. There are a few uncommon types of audio amplifier where rail noise directly wiggles the output, so for this sort, you absolutely require a stable, quiet linear supply.
4. 90 dB SPL is a pretty good value for "loud enough" in an audio system, unless you're building concert hall or stadium sound systems.
5. By definition, 0 dB SPL is the human threshold of inaudibility.
6. Notice that that article doesn't even *try* to cover electrolytics, which are terribly nonlinear. Yet, a lot of audio systems do use them for audio coupling.

Comment: The original IBM PC had a 65 watt supply, and that had to power the hard drive and a floppy as well as the motherboard, graphics card, etc.

Comment: @supercat: Okay. :) The [XT used a 130 W supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer_XT). I looked into the [Apple //c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_//c) not long ago and found that it was also sized around that level, which is interesting given that it had basically no expansion, hence no need for power supply headroom. (Sorry, no online reference. I had to dig into paper manuals to come up with that one.)

Comment: What were the voltage and current specs on the Apple//c supply?  If it's outputting 5 volts, that would be 26 amps.  I don't recall the brick having been large enough to be anything near a 100W linear supply, and given the vintage I wouldn't expect a switcher.

Comment: BTW, is 0dB an actual or theoretical threshold?  I can't imagine any circumstance where a typical person would be able to recognize the presence or absence of a signal with an SPL of only 1dB or even 10dB.  Possibly between heartbeats, but even then I'd have by doubts.  I do think it's worth noting that power supply noises have an amazing and annoying ability to audibly inject themselves where they shouldn't, and that reason by itself could easily justify use of a separate supply, but I don't think realistic detectability goes even close to 0dB.

Comment: @supercat: **Re: Apple //c power**, I misread the spec the last time I looked into it. [It is 1.2A](https://archive.org/stream/Apple_IIc_Technical_Reference_Manual#page/n260/mode/1up), which I assumed was the *input* current (so 144W @ 120V) but it is the output, so it is actually ~24W at 12V. [The IIe power supply can peak at 80W](https://archive.org/stream/Apple_IIe_Technical_Reference_Manual#page/n192/mode/1up). Both are switching designs, per specs on neighboring pages.

Comment: @supercat: **Re: Absolute limit of hearing**, [it depends on the person, the frequency, and their age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_hearing). According to the article, it looks like young children can *approach* 0 dB SPL @ 1 kHz. Perhaps the level of silence was defined as 0 dB before measurement equipment got sensitive enough to find the exact value. Or, perhaps whoever defined it decided to add another 3-6 dB below what they were measuring as a minimum as "enough".

Comment: @WarrenYoung, thank you for this detailed explanation. Although, I would have liked to see it mentioned that some of the described supply issues could be mitigated a degree with say a pi (capacitor inductor capacitor), filter.

Comment: @keithreynolds: That takes care of only some of those problems, leaving the others making this "still not a good idea."

Answer (score 4):

If you have the same sound system as him and therefore only need 10 Watts, it shouldn't be a problem. Most computer power supplies are 300-1000 watt deals so 10 watts shouldn't cause it any heartburn unless the system is already strapped for juice.

Comment: I think that some audio amplifiers may need power supply ground separation. I think thats the reason why many (if not all) simple computer speakers have separate power supply instead of USB connection. I mean ground loops and other issues.

Comment: @kamil definitely not all.  I have plenty of usb powered speakers.  They are generally sold for use with laptops.

Comment: Yea, but probably there is no analog signal in USB speakers, and no ground loop.

Comment: Computer speakers have seperate power supplies more because there isn't enough power on the line-out to drive the speakers in the first place.

Comment: @Kamil whatsisname is right, it's a lack of power, not an issue with signal or grounds that is the reason external power supplies are often used. All speakers need an analog signal at some point (even if it's a digital signal converted to an analog one just before the speaker itself).

Answer (score 1):

Audio amplifiers are kind of difficult load for power supply, because power demand change very fast over time, however for low power audio amplifier (10-20W) and high power supply with big output capacitors there should be no problems with voltage stability.

However - on some power supplies and audio devices - you can have major audio quality problems or huge noises, because of audio signal ground may be connected to amplifier ground supply.

High power audio amplifier always need higher voltage and symmetric supply. Computer power supply can't do that, so there is no point to consider this.

The exception are 12V car audio amplifiers, with built-in dc/dc converters. They have single supply and high power. You can have some voltage stability problems if you connect computer power supply to high power car audio amplifier with DC/DC converter designed to work on very low impedance source.

Answer (score 1):

I had also a 10W switching audio amplifier which was powered from PSU which also supplied a PC. The sound was very noisy, if i started to copy a file in hard drive (or any disk operation was in progress) or i moved the mouse (connected though USB) i heard the noise, if i gave much gain, the noise was also greater. The amplifiers amplifies also the noise of the power line. If you need to supply from PSU, you maybe need to apply a filter/stabiliser for the incoming power line before the amplifier. If your amplifier like a car audio amplifier (as Kamil wrote) which has builtin DC/DC converter, the power line noise no significant (most DC/DC has builtin stabiliser,filter). In this case the impedance is relatively enough "low". A 10W amplifier not required same power line impedance like a amplifier with hundreds of W. If amp. has builtin DC/DC converter your ground loop issue is also solved if your power line ground and jack shield is not short circuited.

Answer (score 1):

I used to power my 60W speakers from PC supply on my own PC. It was working well. The only problem was, I was hearing the sound of hard drive motor activity from the speaker. For example, when Windows power management wakes up an hard drive from sleep mode, I was both hearing it directly from hard drive, and from the speaker as a noise. Any possible ripple on the 12V rail of the PC supply was being heard in the speakers. But that wasn't much of a problem, since it wasn't happening frequently.